Subtracting values from separate source table sequentially/ running values
I am working in SQL Server. I have a scenario where I have dollar amounts from various cost transactions (which I'll call Cashflow) and a set of funding items. Each cashflow transaction and funding item is tied to a project via a column called ProjectId. There can be thousands of cashflow transactions, and I need to display which funding item(s) those cashflow transactions will draw from.
Some items to consider:

Each cashflow row can be funded by multiple funding items if needed
The DepletionOrder column specifies in what order the funding items should be used for a particular project
If there is still money left in a funding item after a cashflow transaction has drawn down against it, the next cashflow transaction (in order of the CashflowRowNum) should continue drawing against the same funding item

Consider the following test DLL and data:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Funding
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Cashflow

CREATE TABLE #Funding 
(
    ProjectId BIGINT,
    DepletionOrder BIGINT,
    FundingAmount DECIMAL(32,2)
)

CREATE TABLE #Cashflow 
(
    ProjectId BIGINT,
    CashflowRowNum BIGINT,
    CashflowAmount DECIMAL(32,2),
)

INSERT INTO #Funding
VALUES 
(1, 1, 1000000),
(1, 2,10000), 
(1, 3, 400),
(1, 4, 40000),
(2, 1, 50000), 
(2, 2, 25000)

INSERT INTO #Cashflow
VALUES 
(1, 1, 999000),
(1, 2, 8000),
(1, 3, 4000),
(2, 1, 60000),
(2, 2, 20000),
(2, 3, 30000)

Here are the results I'm expecting. To be honest, I'm really just trying to figure out how to get ProjectId, CashflowRowNum, DepletionOrder and CashflowFunded all in the same query result.
Everything else I just included it for visibility:



ProjectId
CashflowRowNum
DepletionOrder
CashflowAmount
FundingAmount
CashflowFunded
CashflowRemainingToFund
FundingRemaining




1
1
1
999000
1000000
999000
0
1000


1
2
1
8000
1000000
1000
7000
0


1
2
2
8000
10000
7000
0
3000


1
3
2
4000
10000
3000
1000
0


1
3
3
4000
400
400
600
0


1
3
4
4000
40000
600
0
39400


2
1
1
60000
50000
50000
10000
0


2
1
2
60000
20000
10000
0
10000


2
2
2
20000
60000
10000
10000
0


2
2
3
20000
5000
5000
5000
0



I saw some very similar posts like this one, and I am sure there is a solution that involves window functions and/or recursive CTEs, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to use them for this exact scenario. I am also a bit concerned with the performance of a recursive CTE if CashflowRowNum gets in the 1000s.
Note I also do not want to use cursors or while loops. That would certainly simplify things, but I do not think it would perform well given the number of rows in the Cashflow table.
EDIT:
The comments bring up some fair points. I suppose I should have tried the cursor-based approach to see if it is actually "too slow" before writing it off.
I originally didn't post my attempts with the recursive CTE since I wasn't even getting remotely close. However, using HABO's recursive CTE approach in the post linked above, I think I am about 95% there. I have CashflowRemainingToFund and FundingRemaining calculating correctly, but I cannot figure out the proper formula for CashflowFunded which is what I ultimately need. The bottom portion of the UNION is what I can't figure out. It seems straightforward enough to conceptualize, but writing it out in in the recursive CTE has me stumped. Any ideas?
;with Cashflow as (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(CashflowAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY CashflowRowNum) AS CashflowRunningTotalByProject
    FROM #Cashflow
),
Funding as (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(FundingAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY DepletionOrder) AS FundingRunningTotalByProject
    FROM #Funding
),
CashflowFunding as (
    select f.ProjectId, 
        f.DepletionOrder, 
        CashflowRowNum,
        CashflowRunningTotalByProject,
        f.FundingAmount, 
        f.FundingRunningTotalByProject,
        cf.CashflowAmount,
        convert(
            decimal(32,2),
            case
                when cf.CashflowAmount IS NULL 
                    then f.FundingAmount
                when f.FundingAmount >= CashflowRunningTotalByProject
                    then f.FundingAmount - CashflowRunningTotalByProject
                when f.FundingAmount < CashflowRunningTotalByProject
                    then 0
            end
        ) as FundingRemaining,
        convert(
            decimal(32,2),
            case
                when cf.CashflowAmount IS NULL 
                    then 0
                when f.FundingAmount >= CashflowRunningTotalByProject
                    then 0
                when f.FundingAmount < CashflowRunningTotalByProject
                    then CashflowRunningTotalByProject - f.FundingAmount
            end
        ) as CashflowRemainingToFund,
        convert(
            decimal(32,2),
            case
                when cf.CashflowAmount IS NULL 
                    then null
                when f.FundingAmount >= cf.CashflowRunningTotalByProject
                    then CashflowAmount
                when f.FundingAmount < cf.CashflowRunningTotalByProject
                    then CashflowAmount + (f.FundingAmount - CashflowRunningTotalByProject)
            end
        ) as CashflowFunded
    from Funding as f 
        left join Cashflow as cf on cf.ProjectId = f.ProjectId
    where f.DepletionOrder = 1
  
    union all

    select f.ProjectId, 
        f.DepletionOrder, 
        CTE.CashflowRowNum,
        CashflowRunningTotalByProject,
        f.FundingAmount, 
        f.FundingRunningTotalByProject,
        CTE.CashflowAmount,
        convert(
            decimal(32,2),
            case
                when f.FundingAmount >= CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund then f.FundingAmount - CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund
                when f.FundingAmount < CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund then 0
            end
        ) as FundingRemaining,
        convert(
            decimal(32,2),
            case
                when CTE.FundingRemaining + f.FundingAmount >= CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund then 0
                when CTE.FundingRemaining + f.FundingAmount < CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund then CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund - CTE.FundingRemaining - f.FundingAmount
            end
        ) as CashflowRemainingToFund,

        /*this part is incorrect*/
        convert(
            decimal(32,2),
            case
                when f.FundingAmount >= CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund then CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund
                when f.FundingAmount < CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund then CTE.FundingRemaining - f.FundingAmount
            end
        ) as CashflowFunded
    from CashflowFunding as CTE 
        inner join Funding as f on f.ProjectId = CTE.ProjectId 
            and f.DepletionOrder = CTE.DepletionOrder + 1
    where CTE.CashflowRemainingToFund > 0
)
select 
    *,
    SUM(CashflowRemainingToFund) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId, CashflowRowNum ORDER BY DepletionOrder) AS SumCfRemaining,
    case when DepletionOrder = ( select max( DepletionOrder ) from #Funding where ProjectId = CashflowFunding.ProjectId ) 
        then FundingRemaining - CashflowRemainingToFund
        else NULL 
    end as SurplusOrDeficit
from CashflowFunding
where CashflowRemainingToFund <= CashflowAmount
order by ProjectId, DepletionOrder, CashflowRowNum

For now, I'll likely write a cursor to do it anyway, but I find this approach pretty interesting so I'd like to finish it off if possible. Thanks in advance for any help.

Cursors can perform very well in this scenario (one scan, read-only), and as you said: simple; you shouldn't simply ignore them.

Why do you think a cursor wouldn't perform well? I doubt this. Maybe just try out?

@JonasMetzler i suspect this is one of those give me teh codez question. Cursors is fine for this task, you can also use a loop where on each iteration you take one project at a time and one cashflow item, if you have a lot of projects

As a cursor would be not so difficult to write for this, why don't you write it and test it's performance. If it behaves well enough then just use it, you can still rewrite after trying this out

See performance rant. I was going to suggest that you try the accepted answer to the question you linked, but you don't seem to like the recursive CTE it uses. Have a go at writing a query and edit it into your question. We can help you with fixing it.

@HABO Just posted some edits. The performance rant article makes some good points, and as noted in the article, perhaps I should have just written the cursor-based approach to see if it had any issues. It's not that I didn't like your recursive CTE answer; in fact, I think it's a very interesting solution. For some reason I thought I would need to recurse through thousands of Cashflow rows (which may not have been an issue), but now I see it can be done using my Funding rows, which will have far fewer rows per project. I just posted some updates. If you have any insights, I'd appreciate it.

This appears to be a FIFO (First-In, First-Out) allocation problem.
This can be solved without a loop by calculating the accumulated start/stop ranges for each source (funding), calculating the same for each sink (cash flow), and then identifying the overlaps between the source and sink ranges.
The ranges can be calculated using a running-sum SUM(...) OVER(...) window functions. Overlaps can be identified using the condition start1 < end2 AND start2 < end1. The actual overlap range (and size) can be calculated  as GREATEST(start1, start2) through LEAST(end1, end2). All calculations are done separately for each partition (ProjectId)
WITH CummulativeFunding AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(FundingAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY DepletionOrder)
            - FundingAmount
            AS FromAmount,
        SUM(FundingAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY DepletionOrder)
            AS ToAmount
    FROM #Funding
),
CummulativeCashFlow AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(CashflowAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY CashflowRowNum)
            - CashflowAmount
            AS FromAmount,
        SUM(CashflowAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY CashflowRowNum)
            AS ToAmount
    FROM #Cashflow
)
SELECT
    CCF.ProjectId,
    CCF.CashflowRowNum,
    CF.DepletionOrder,
    CCF.CashflowAmount,
    CF.FundingAmount,
    OVL.ToAmount - OVL.FromAmount AS CashflowFunded,
    CCF.ToAmount - OVL.ToAmount AS CashflowRemainingToFund,
    CF.ToAmount - OVL.ToAmount AS FundingRemaining
FROM CummulativeFunding CF
JOIN CummulativeCashFlow CCF
    ON CCF.ProjectId = CF.ProjectId
    AND CCF.FromAmount < CF.ToAmount
    AND CF.FromAmount < CCF.ToAmount
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        -- For SQL Server versions 2022 and later
        GREATEST(CF.FromAmount, CCF.FromAmount) AS FromAmount,
        LEAST(CF.ToAmount, CCF.ToAmount) AS ToAmount
        -- For earlier SQL Server versions
        --IIF(CF.FromAmount > CCF.FromAmount ,CF.FromAmount, CCF.FromAmount) AS FromAmount,
        --IIF(CF.ToAmount < CCF.ToAmount ,CF.ToAmount, CCF.ToAmount) AS ToAmount
) OVL
ORDER BY CF.ProjectId, OVL.FromAmount

The LEAST() and GREATEST() functions are available in SQL Server versions 2022 and later. For earlier versions, an equivalent CASE expression or IIF() function can be used.
You might need separate logic to identify remaining funding or unfunded cash flows, if the source and sink totals differ.
Results:



ProjectId
CashflowRowNum
DepletionOrder
CashflowAmount
FundingAmount
CashflowFunded
CashflowRemainingToFund
FundingRemaining




1
1
1
999000.00
1000000.00
999000.00
0.00
1000.00


1
2
1
8000.00
1000000.00
1000.00
7000.00
0.00


1
2
2
8000.00
10000.00
7000.00
0.00
3000.00


1
3
2
4000.00
10000.00
3000.00
1000.00
0.00


1
3
3
4000.00
400.00
400.00
600.00
0.00


1
3
4
4000.00
40000.00
600.00
0.00
39400.00


2
1
1
60000.00
50000.00
50000.00
10000.00
0.00


2
1
2
60000.00
25000.00
10000.00
0.00
15000.00


2
2
2
20000.00
25000.00
15000.00
5000.00
0.00



Some of the CashflowFunded amounts calculated above do not match the posted desired results, but they do appear to be consistent with the sample source data.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Thanks, this is great! I love the notes regarding the more modern vs older TSQL as well. My bad regarding the sample data; the data shown in your query results is indeed correct. I'll correct it. Much appreciated.
